Cert-Manager fails renewal of certificates with "SERVFAIL"
I am running a small K3S cluster and I use Cert-Manager to issue Let's Encrypt certificates to the applications running in my cluster.
The cluster was installed via Ansible and the initial generation of certificates worked fine, but for some odd reason Cert-Manager will not renew the certificates?
A quick reference: Main main domain is molgaard.eu, which hosted by Simply.com.
The cluster resides at home.molgaard.eu, which is a subdomain that is not accessible from the Internet, hence in order issue Let's Encrypt certificates on the form: (something).home.molgaard.eu I need make sure Cert-Manager uses dns01 during renewal.
This is all handled by the following Ansible task:
- name: Create Lets Encrypt ClusterIssuer
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
      kind: ClusterIssuer
      metadata:
        name: letsencrypt-prod
      spec:
        acme:
          email: *** REDACTED ***
          server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
          privateKeySecretRef:
            name: letsencrypt-prod-private-key
          solvers:
            - dns01:
                webhook:
                  groupName: com.github.runnerm.cert-manager-simply-webhook
                  solverName: simply-dns-solver
                  config:
                    secretName: simply-credentials
              selector:
                dnsZones:
                  - molgaard.eu


This part worked fine when I created the cluster, but when renewal came around, something went apparently wrong:
Here is what happens when I try to debug the challenge created for the renewal the certificate for unifi.home.molgaard.eu.
The relevant excerpt from kubectl get challenges unifi-tls-2-3236526805-1144319786 -ojson is as follows:
    "status": {
        "presented": false,
        "processing": true,
        "reason": "When querying the SOA record for the domain '_acme-challenge.unifi.home.molgaard.eu.' using nameservers [8.8.8.8:53 1.1.1.1:53], rcode was expected to be 'NOERROR' or 'NXDOMAIN', but I got 'SERVFAIL'",
        "state": "pending"
    }

I know it is DNS related and I would expect that when asking for SOA, it would point towards the DNS servers hosted by Simply.com?
Searching a bit online I do find a discussion about cert-manager having issues with SOA lookups, but I do not know if it is applicable for my issue?

there's no reachable authority for home.molgaard.eu - have you changed (or added) some DNS records recently? note: the DNS records you need exist on ns1.simply.com, they just don't seem to have propagated.

No change at all to DNS, although I do have a local Bind9 server that handles request for the subdomain home.molgaard.eu, but I have explicitly told cert-manager to use Google and CloudFlare DNS for DNS resolving issuing and renewing Let's Encrypt certificates, so that should not be an issue ... or? Should I have created a local CNAME record like _acme-challenge.unifi.home.molgaard.eu CNAME _acme-challenge.molgaard.eu and told cert-manager to use local DNS and added cnameStrategy: Follow to my Ansible script instead?

I have explicitly told cert-manager to use Google and CloudFlare DNS for DNS resolving issuing and renewing Let's Encrypt certificates, so that should not be an issue - well, how can lets encrypt resolve the addresses it needs since lets encrypt can't access your local bind server to resolve them??? but ns1.simply.com DOES resolve the addresses, not sure why they haven't propagated anywhere

how does ns1.simply.com know about unifi.home.molgaard.eu but 8.8.8.8 doesn't?

Well cert-manager has a API key that it uses to create the record _acme-challenge.unifi.home.molgaard.eu. It is stored in the credentials simply-credentials from my Ansible task. During the initial dns01 validation it had no issue creating the record at Simply.com. Also: Why would 8.8.8.8 need to know what the ip address unifi.home.molgaard.eu? It resolves to a RFC1918 address and is not needed, since I use dns01 and not http-01. Which means I prove I have access to the DNS server and not the webserver of the domain.

DNS-01 challenge - your client will create a TXT record derived from that token and your account key, and put that record at _acme-challenge.<YOUR_DOMAIN>. Then Let’s Encrypt will query the DNS system for that record. If it finds a match, you can proceed to issue a certificate! - basically, ns-home.molgaard.eu has to accessible to lets encrypt so it can read the TXT record you set

D'oh! I guess the NS record for home.molgaard.eu at Simply.com made cert-manager go fubar? The only way the Internet can access my local DNS server is via IPv6 ... and my router says IPv6 is currently down for some odd reason. I deleted the record, so lets see if that help, because it should tell the Internet to use only Simply.com for all requests against my domain and subdomains.

But the _acme-challenge. TXT record must be accessible to lets encrypt servers

Deletion of NS record worked like a charm. I can see cert-manager have created a valud lets encrypt certificate. @JaromandaX: Kan you add an answer so I can credit you for finding the issue? ;-)

To be honest, I'm not sure what the issue was. I mean I know what I said, but I don't know what your setup looks like

It was a DNS issue at Simply.com. ns-home record (which you found) was interfering with cert-manager. ns-home was handling the subdomain home.molgaard.eu which is only accessible via IPv6 and IPv6 was down. Also 8.8.8.8 was never supposed to lookup my local DNS server, so by deleting the record made Simply.com answer for all lookups against my domain and subdomains.
